# Javascript Add input value within characters in output

Tags: javascript, input, output

I've tried to make A input text box & an output text box with a convert button where, if someone clicks the convert button, the input must be displayed in the output box with some change. but it didn't work.

For example,

If the input is "**something**"

The output should be "**@@:{something}0**"

that is , input value must be present within the characters i specify.

Can someone get me the code for this?

Here's my code so far:

```
function ConvertText() { 
    document.form1.outstring.value = document.form1.instring.value.to@@{
                                        instring.value}0();
                                     }

<form name="form1" method="post"> <input name="instring" type="text" value="" size="50">

    <input type="button" name="Convert" value="Convert" onClick="ConvertText();">
    <input name="outstring" type="text" value="" size="50"> 
</form>
```

Comment: This is my first venture, so regret for my blunders.

function ConvertText() {
  document.form1.outstring.value = document.form1.instring.value.to@@:{instring.value}0();
}




<form name="form1" method="post">
<input name="instring" type="text" value="" size="50">
<input type="button" name="Convert" value="Convert" onClick="ConvertText();">
<input name="outstring" type="text" value="" size="50">
</form>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without spilling all the code. Here is some JavaScript of how to get the value of an input field and make some modifications. And then how to set that string to the value of the output field.

**In your html**

```
<input id="first"></input>
<input id="output"></input>
```

**In your javascript** (*The event is not included*)

```
document.getElementById('first').value
```

And you can append some stuff to that string.

```
var string = document.getElementById('first').value
var newString = "@@:{"+string+"}0"
```

And.. heres what you want.

```
document.getElementById('output').value = newString
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you have trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

​`<input type="text" id="box1"><br/>`

```
<input type="text" id="box2"><br/>
<input type='button' onclick='convert()' value='convert'>

​function convert() {
    var value1=document.getElementById('box1').value;
    document.getElementById('box2').value = '@@:{'+value1+'}0';
}​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d74h4/1/)

Comment: It works.

I've been trying out the codes in tinkerbin.com When i run the code in tinkerbin the result was negative. It didn't work.
But in jsfiddle.net it works like a charm.
Which one should i rely upon ?

Comment: @magicramki it should work everywhere, can you give me the link for tinkerbin.com

Comment: @sibu u know, i'm very much new to this. moreover, Jimmy's worked on the very first try even on tinkerbin. Regrets :(

Comment: @magicramki its okay, you got your answer that what matters :-)